# Solution to get output for python project

Tags: python

I am doing a simple project on my Pycharm IDE. 
My code is this:

```
import webbrowser
import time
socialMediaUrls = ["www.google.com","www.edureka.com"]
techUrls = ["www.udacity.com","www.dailymotion.com"]

def open_tabs(url_list):
    for element in url_list:
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(element)

def main():
    webbrowser.open("www.youtube.com",new=0,autoraise=false)
    time.sleep(1)
    open.tab(socialMedialUrls)
    open_tabs(techUrls)

    main()
```

but after running I am getting this message:

> C:\Users\adc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
>   C:/Users/adc/PycharmProjects/untitled1/ur.py
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

And I am getting same message for all my projects. What should I do?

Comment: It looks like you have some serious issues with your code structure. Where is `main()` being called?

Comment: check indentation: main() calls itself, therefore is never really called: your script does nothing

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre probably just the OP's typo since s/he has mentioned `Process finished with exit code 0`...

Answer (score 0):

You should call `main` in that way:

```
def main():
    webbrowser.open("www.youtube.com",new=0,autoraise=false)
    time.sleep(1)
    open.tab(socialMedialUrls)
    open_tabs(techUrls)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Also I see that your code contains some other errors. For example, in Python there is `False` keyword, not `false`. Lines with `open.tab` and `open_tabs` will not work too.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, no instructions are reachable in your script (besides the `import` statements)

in:

```
def main():
    webbrowser.open("www.youtube.com",new=0,autoraise=false)
    time.sleep(1)
    open.tab(socialMedialUrls)
    open_tabs(techUrls)

    main()
```

indentation suggests that you're performing a *recursive call* (which isn't what you want).

Unindent `main()` to make sure you execute something in your script.

Or put the instructions of `main` at zero-indent level outside any procedure (in that case, it is executed even when importing the module, probably not important here)

(note that python programs don't need a `main()`, this isn't C)